# Can I skip an indirect flight?

Tags: air-travel, lhr, jfk

I wanted to book a direct flight from Heathrow to JFK with BA. Over night they put the price up by over £500. Now I can see the exact same flight but you have to go indirect via Newcastle to Heathrow to JFK, it works out way cheaper this way.

Is there anyway I can skip the Newcastle flight if I contact BA before and go direct to Heathrow or if I miss the Newcastle flight will the whole flight be cancelled?

Answer (score 2):

If you contact BA to cancel ths Newcastle leg, they will reprice the ticket out of London at the fare that is avaiable that day, which likely will be higher, plus a change fee.

If you skip the first flight without notifying them, then all subsequent flights will be cancelled.

If the fare is that much better, why not take the train to Newcastle and fly from there.

Comment: Booked in advance, you can get it for less. Still 4 hours though... BA one-way single flight might not be too much more, could always fly up, have a drink then fly back on your connecting long haul!